# Translate SQL Server 2008 Cursor Variables to SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm attempting to port the database for NetSqlAzMan to Azure. I'm running into a problem with a few of the stored procedures.

```
SET @member_cur = CURSOR STATIC FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM @RESULT
OPEN @member_cur
```

results in error message:

> Msg 16948, Level 16, State 4
>   Procedure
>   netsqlazman_GetApplicationGroupSidMembers,
>   Line 118
>   The variable '@member_cur' is
>   not a cursor variable, but it is used
>   in a place where a cursor variable is
>   expected.

The store procedure script was created by exporting an empty NetSQLAzMan database in SQLAzure format. Any tips for handling cursor variables in SQL Azure? I don't see much for documentation on this.

Here is the stored procedure if that helps. Please pardon the verbosity. The error references the bottom of the stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[netsqlazman_GetApplicationGroupSidMembers]
    @ISMEMBER [bit],
    @GROUPOBJECTSID [varbinary](85),
    @NETSQLAZMANMODE [bit],
    @LDAPPATH [nvarchar](4000),
    @member_cur [int] OUTPUT
WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS
DECLARE @RESULT TABLE (objectSid VARBINARY(85))
DECLARE @GROUPID INT
DECLARE @GROUPTYPE TINYINT
DECLARE @LDAPQUERY nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @sub_members_cur CURSOR
DECLARE @OBJECTSID VARBINARY(85)
SELECT @GROUPID = ApplicationGroupId, @GROUPTYPE = GroupType, @LDAPQUERY = LDapQuery FROM [netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupsTable] WHERE objectSid = @GROUPOBJECTSID
IF @GROUPTYPE = 0 -- BASIC
BEGIN
    --memo: WhereDefined can be:0 - Store; 1 - Application; 2 - LDAP; 3 - Local; 4 - Database
    -- Windows SIDs
    INSERT INTO @RESULT (objectSid) 
    SELECT objectSid 
    FROM dbo.[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupMembersTable]
    WHERE 
    ApplicationGroupId = @GROUPID AND IsMember = @ISMEMBER AND
    ((@NETSQLAZMANMODE = 0 AND (WhereDefined = 2 OR WhereDefined = 4)) OR (@NETSQLAZMANMODE = 1 AND WhereDefined BETWEEN 2 AND 4))
    -- Store Groups Members
    DECLARE @MemberObjectSid VARBINARY(85)
    DECLARE @MemberType bit
    DECLARE @NotMemberType bit
    DECLARE nested_Store_groups_cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT objectSid, IsMember FROM dbo.[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupMembersTable] WHERE ApplicationGroupId = @GROUPID AND WhereDefined = 0

    OPEN nested_Store_groups_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM nested_Store_groups_cur INTO @MemberObjectSid, @MemberType
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            -- recursive call
        IF @ISMEMBER = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @MemberType = 0 
                SET @NotMemberType = 0
            ELSE
                SET @NotMemberType = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @MemberType = 0 
                SET @NotMemberType = 1
            ELSE
                SET @NotMemberType = 0
        END
        EXEC dbo.[netsqlazman_GetStoreGroupSidMembers] @NotMemberType, @MemberObjectSid, @NETSQLAZMANMODE, @LDAPPATH, @sub_members_cur OUTPUT
        FETCH NEXT FROM @sub_members_cur INTO @OBJECTSID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES (@OBJECTSID)
            FETCH NEXT FROM @sub_members_cur INTO @OBJECTSID
        END     
        CLOSE @sub_members_cur
        DEALLOCATE @sub_members_cur         

        FETCH NEXT FROM nested_Store_groups_cur INTO @MemberObjectSid, @MemberType
    END
    CLOSE nested_Store_groups_cur
    DEALLOCATE nested_Store_groups_cur

    -- Application Groups Members
    DECLARE nested_Application_groups_cur CURSOR LOCAL FAST_FORWARD FOR
        SELECT objectSid, IsMember FROM dbo.[netsqlazman_ApplicationGroupMembersTable] WHERE ApplicationGroupId = @GROUPID AND WhereDefined = 1

    OPEN nested_Application_groups_cur
    FETCH NEXT FROM nested_Application_groups_cur INTO @MemberObjectSid, @MemberType
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
            -- recursive call
        IF @ISMEMBER = 1
        BEGIN
            IF @MemberType = 0 
                SET @NotMemberType = 0
            ELSE
                SET @NotMemberType = 1
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            IF @MemberType = 0 
                SET @NotMemberType = 1
            ELSE
                SET @NotMemberType = 0
        END
        EXEC dbo.[netsqlazman_GetApplicationGroupSidMembers] @NotMemberType, @MemberObjectSid, @NETSQLAZMANMODE, @LDAPPATH, @sub_members_cur OUTPUT
        FETCH NEXT FROM @sub_members_cur INTO @OBJECTSID
        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO @RESULT VALUES (@OBJECTSID)
            FETCH NEXT FROM @sub_members_cur INTO @OBJECTSID
        END     
        CLOSE @sub_members_cur
        DEALLOCATE @sub_members_cur 

        FETCH NEXT FROM nested_Application_groups_cur INTO @MemberObjectSid, @MemberType
    END
    CLOSE nested_Application_groups_cur
    DEALLOCATE nested_Application_groups_cur
    END
ELSE IF @GROUPTYPE = 1 AND @ISMEMBER = 1 -- LDAP QUERY
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.[netsqlazman_ExecuteLDAPQuery] @LDAPPATH, @LDAPQUERY, @sub_members_cur OUTPUT
    FETCH NEXT FROM @sub_members_cur INTO @OBJECTSID
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @RESULT (objectSid) VALUES (@OBJECTSID)
        FETCH NEXT FROM @sub_members_cur INTO @OBJECTSID
    END
    CLOSE @sub_members_cur
    DEALLOCATE @sub_members_cur
END
SET @member_cur = CURSOR STATIC FORWARD_ONLY FOR SELECT * FROM @RESULT
OPEN @member_cur
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this problem is with cursors so much but more with the declaration of the output variable.  If you look at the start of the stored procedure you have this:

```
@member_cur [int] OUTPUT
```

Where `@member_cur` is defined as being an integer.  You're then trying to assign it to have the value of a cursor and it is rightly complaining.  What I'm surprised about is that this is what was generated from a non-Azure SQL Server.  Either way it looks like SQL Azure doesn't support this, so either change the type of the output parameter, or open your cursor in a different variable and assign @member_cur to be that value.